# firebase facebook javascript sdk photoURL is a generic profile image

Tags: reactjs, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook authentication in my react/firebase project and I'm getting the user object back just fine with all of the other info I need such as displayName and email.  However, the photoURL is just a generic profile image and not my actual Fb profile photo.  Any help from someone familiar with using firebase Facebook auth would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Facebook changed the requirements a while ago, in most situations the request for the profile picture URL now needs an access token, otherwise it will just return the generic silhouette. (But don't ask me how to fix that within firebase, I wouldn't know.)